# Bolean and Knife Project add Artifacts? Best/Cleanest Way of Adding Details to Mesh?

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface, artifacts

I am trying to model a turntable and want to add a hole where a button is placed. I am struggling to add this whole as I tried to add it with a boolean modifier and with a knife project. I Guess the problem is the subdivision modifier in combination with the N-Gons but I dont know what the best practice is to model such a simpel Cube with a hole in it

My Mesh:
[image]

Boolean:
[image]

Knife Project:
[image]

Comment: It's pretty old now but there's a quick tutorial from 
CG Cookie on avoiding the problems you're seeing when using the boolean modifier [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGJYkAKQoT8) which might help.

Comment: Thank you I will try..  but from looking shortly over it, it seems more as dirty fix for a not so good workflow. Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: It's really correcting a limitation that you'll always come up against when using a boolean. The same thing applies to using knife project too.

Comment: First of all: It helped and now looks good.

I Understand that, but what would be the "clean"/"correct" way of doing it, if not with boolean or knife project?

Comment: There isn't really a "correct" way. If you Google "blender making holes near edge of object" you'l get a variety of suggestions and tutorials using different methods.